# Arduino IDE unable to Compile Sketch

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to compile the basic blink sketch in the Arduino IDE, however anytime I try to compile the sketch, I get this error:

"C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\tools\arduino101load\2.0.1/arduino101load" -c "-from=\"C:\Users\MY" "PC\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_712395/Fade.ino.elf\"" "-to=\"C:\Users\MY" "PC\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_712395/../arduino101_sketch.debug.elf\""

ERROR: need -from and -to arguments

Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which Arduino board do you have, an Arduino 101 or an Arduino Uno (as indicated by the tag)? They are very much not the same thing.

Comment: @per1234 its a genuino101. Apologies for the incorrect tags. Is it relevant which board I'm using, since it's a compile error and not an upload error?

Comment: Only relevant in that if you had an Uno we could have sidestepped the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I don't think the curie core installed correctly initially, so I removed it and reinstalled it.